# Will a website still work if parts of the site have compilation errors?

Tags: asp.net, deployment, compilation

Will a website still work if parts of the site have compilation errors?

Comment: You seem to be asking two different questions, could you rephrase? An ASP.Net website is typically compiled into one assembly, so if you have build errors the site will not work.

Answer (score 1):

> It depends on how you have deployed
>   your website. There basically two main
>   strategies to deploy
>  
>   an asp.net application.

***1.) PreCompiled deployment***

In precompiled deployment you will have all your code-behind files compiled into assemblies. Further, if you are using Web Deployment projects then all those compiled assemblies will be merged into one single assembly.

So In PreCompiled deployment your website cannot be deployed without any error anywhere in the Project.

***2.) XCopy deployment***

In XCopy deployement you will just copy-paste your entire website to production server without compilation. In this case, only those pages are compiled,loaded and served which are requested via an HttpClient. If you have an asp.net page that has some errors, your website will not show up those error until that has been requested via any HttpClient. Remaining website continues to work without any effect from those with errors.